# Is it possible to setup eslint on webpack.config.babel.js without CommonJS warning/error?

Tags: webpack, eslint, webpack-5

As title. I want to use ES6 modules syntax on my webpack config file. Currently, I got:

```
Diagnostics:
Cannot use import declarations in modules that export using CommonJS (module.exports = 'foo' or exports.bar = 'hi') [import/no-import-module-exports]
```

Answer (score 0):

To use ES6 modules syntax in your `webpack.config.js`(and you don't need the `.babel.` in the middle), do the following:

1. `package.json` add `"type": "module"`
2. In `webpack.config.js` change Node.js `module.exports` to `export default`.
3. In `webpack.config.js` change CJS `__dirname`,`__filename` to `path.dirname()`,`import.meta.url` with some modifications.